Bootstrap test should give one sided confidence interval for the composite hypothesis
I want to test the hypothesis $H_0:$ $ C_L=\frac{\mu-L}{\sigma}<c$ vs $H_A:$ $C_L= \frac{\mu-L}{\sigma}>c$ for two parameter exponential distribution. I am trying to do percentile bootstrap based testing. I am following a paper named "Generalized confidence limits for the performance index of the exponentially distributed lifetime" for this. In the paper page 765 gives the test and the rejection region is based on 95% lower confidence bound. My questions are,

Should not the test be an upper tailed test, and 95% upper confidence bound should be used instead of 95% lower confidence bound used in paper?
What should be the upper confidence bound when using bootstrapped method?
What should be the rejection criteria?

Did the paper make mistake there?

Please edit the question to provide a more complete reference or, ideally, a web link to the paper you are citing.

What part of the sample space corresponds to $C_L=\frac{\mu-L}{\sigma}=c$, and where does that fit into your hypothesis?

Based on the alternative hypothesis, the 95% confidence range would be the left-tailed (lower 95%) region.
If after you obtain your bootstrapped estimates, if your value of $c$ from the hypotheses does not fall in the top 5%, then you essentially do not have enough evidence to support your claim.  Thus, the "rejection" criteria (for the null hypothesis) is if $c$ falls above your 95th percentile from the bootstraps (that is, your $c$ falls above the lower 95% of the bootstrapped values).
However, if the paper is referring to the rejection region for your claim (ie, not proving the claim)...then the terminology needs to be adjusted accordingly, but the analysis outlined here remains the same).
